# Retrofit - how do I make a synchronous request within an asynchronous request

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, synchronous

I'm implementing a two-level nested `recyclerView` and both recycler views make an API call using `retrofit`. This is the method that makes the synchronous request:

```
public void loadSectionStories(String sessionKey, CuratedSection section) {
    Call<JsonArray> subCall;
    subCall = TravelersApi.endpoint().getCuratedSectionTopics(sessionKey, section.id);

    try {
        Response<JsonArray> response = subCall.execute();
        if(response.code() != 200) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot load page as of the moment.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        JsonArray rawStories = response.body();
        if(rawStories.size() == 0) {
            //TODO: show placeholder
            return;
        }
        ArrayList<CuratedSectionItem> stories = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < rawStories.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject jStories = rawStories.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            JSONObject temp = new JSONObject(jStories.toString());
            JsonObject author = jStories.get("author").getAsJsonObject();
            CuratedSectionItem story = new CuratedSectionItem();
            story.title = jStories.get("title").getAsString();
            story.avatar = author.get("profile_photo").getAsString();
            story.displayPhoto = temp.getString("primary_photo");
            story.username = author.get("username").getAsString();
            story.description = jStories.get("content").getAsString();
            story.topicId = jStories.get("id").getAsString();
            story.postId = jStories.get("first_post_id").getAsString();
            story.hasReacted = false;
            story.upvotes = jStories.get("stats").getAsJsonObject().get("upvotes").getAsInt();
            stories.add(story);
        }
        section.stories = stories;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR!", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the method that makes the asynchronous request and also calls `loadSectionStories` in a thread:

```
public void loadCuratedSections(final int start, final int limit) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("user_session", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String sessionKey = prefs.getString("session_key", null);

    Call<JsonArray> call;
    call = TravelersApi.endpoint().getCuratedSections(sessionKey);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, Response<JsonArray> response) {
            if(response.code() != 200) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot load page as of the moment.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            JsonArray rawSections = response.body();
            if(rawSections.size() == 0) {
                return;
            }
            for (int i = start; i < limit; i++) {
                JsonObject jSection = rawSections.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                final CuratedSection section = new CuratedSection();
                section.id = jSection.get("id").getAsString();
                section.header = jSection.get("section_header").getAsString();
                section.isShown = jSection.get("is_shown").getAsBoolean();

                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loadSectionStories(sessionKey, section);
                    }
                });
                thread.start();
                curatedSections.add(section);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonArray> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("ERROR!", t.toString());
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Everything is working fine except the fact that `section.stories` returns null. It doesn't make sense to me because of this statement `section.stories = stories` inside `loadSectionStories`.

Comment: Try to call the loadSectionStories() outside the Thread, remove the thread and try again.

Comment: @TentenPonce that's what I did originally, but I got a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using section.stories before your synchronous request is completed (which is running in new threads) then it will return null which is currently happening.

so either you have to remove new thread flow if you want to use it after your first asynchronous request is completed,

or you have to reload your recycler view when you stories is updated.

Also why are you executing your synchronous request(loadSectionStories) in new thread, is it not similar to asynchronous request?

Answer (score 0):

```
Retrofit asyncRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(URLS.MAIN_SERVER_URL)
                    // below line create thread for syncrouns request
                    .callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build();
```

this will run your request in asyncronous